# Vim plugins and configuration to make it behaves and look like Sublime?

Tags: linux, software-development, vim

Well, I'm thinking if anyone have a working setup like that. I don't want to mimic all of Sublime's features.

I need the following:

- syntax highlighting for C/C++, Python 3 and Lua;
- auto completion, like starting to type a variable name and it suggests the complete name (Sublime have this by default);
- and the ability to open tabs with files, and put the tabs in arrangements (like 3 tabs open side to side, splitting the screen in 3 parts).

Comment: Try emacs it already has a lot of those.

Answer (score 1):

For code completion in Vim, this works splendidly: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe

Vim already has vsplits and hsplits. Uncertain if you could get tabs in the way you're wanting (more of a terminal thing. I'd suggest looking into Terminator Terminal or iTerm 2 or Byobu or sommat). If you're wanting a folder tree try this: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/README.markdown

Syntax highlighting and linting I haven't looked into in a while. Flake8 is a good Linter for Python, though I can't remember if it does Syntax highlighting or if I had something else that handled Python's syntax... (can't post a link to it, don't have enough reputation. Just Google Flake8 for Vim)